# duplicate a 32GB disk image from a 64GB usbstick

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, usb

I cloned the image of a win10 UEFI installation in 32GB of ssd to a 64 GB USB stick, to enable restoration later. It didn't fit on a 32GB stick. This was achieved with something like
 sudo dd status=progress bs=8M  if=/dev/mmblk0 of=/dev/sda
gparted shows the USB image is about 32GB in 4 partitions with about 32GB unallocated.

I would like to copy this to another stick so I can reduce the windows partition to a size which will fit on a 32GB stick from which I hope to be able to restore the machine.

dd won't copy the 64GB stick to another 64GB stick because they aren't exactly the same size. I will presumably have the same problem restoring the original machine.

I have extracted each partition and can, I hope, restore from these. 
Is there a better way?

Thanks for the feedback, here are the outputs you requested. There is almost no excess space in the last partition except that labeled unallocated by gparted, or do you mean modifying the 64GB image? I was trying not to modify the original copy but a cloned version.

```
#fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdd: 58.2 GiB, 62461575168 bytes, 121995264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E5755FCA-44EB-4549-9833-6AAB557FB39C

Device        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1      2048   534527   532480  260M EFI System
/dev/sdd2    534528   567295    32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdd3    567296 59021311 58454016 27.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdd4  59021312 61069311  2048000 1000M Windows recovery environment

sudo lsblk -f
sdd                                                             
├─sdd1 ext4   NextCloud    f31a3260-dfe1-405f-ad4b-8c389db6fef7 
├─sdd2                                                          
├─sdd3 ntfs   Windows      A874250B7424DDB6                     /media/fred/Windows
└─sdd4 ntfs   WINRE_DRV    CEEA25F1EA25D70D  

#sudo lsblk -m
sdd     58.2G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdd1   260M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdd2    16M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdd3  27.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sdd4  1000M root  disk  brw-rw----
#sudo parted -ls
Model: TOSHIBA USB FLASH DRIVE (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 62.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  274MB   273MB   ext4         EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      274MB   290MB   16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      290MB   30.2GB  29.9GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      30.2GB  31.3GB  1049MB  ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
```

Comment: What is the partition table; MSDOS (old MBR)or GUID (GPT)? Things are a bit more complicated with a GUID partition table because of a backup table at the very end of the drive. But in both cases there are problems to clone/restore to a drive that is smaller (even slightly smaller) than the original drive size, unless you moved the tail end of the 'last' partition, so that it will fit into the target drive. -- If the only problem is the backup partition table, it should be fixed automatically with mkusb, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Expansion_and_imaging_from_a_compressed_image_file

Comment: I'm not at my computer just now so can't be precise, but the original wasn't MBR.      The partition, about 28GB, which I want to shrink is the 3rd  the 4th is a recovery partition which I intended to move so the whole image would be about 1GB less than 32.   But I could just install the recovery partition and hope it does what it says.

Comment: It is better to shrink the last partition (where it is correct, the original one or a cloned copy, which is not truncated because of lack of drive space). I think there will be problems with a truncated partiiton on the final cloned copy. It might help if you *edit your original question* to add the output of the following commands, when the original drive one or a full (not truncated) cloned copy is connected, and also the target drive, which might be less than 32 GB (undersized), `sudo lsblk -f  ;  sudo lsblk -m  ;  sudo parted -ls`

Comment: The end of `/dev/sdd4` is at 31.3GB, sector `61069311`. Will this fit in the target drive? You need to run those commands with the target drive connected to find out exactly how big it is.

Comment: the last sector on the target (64GB USB stick) is 120127487 but that is  less than the 121995264 total sectors of the original copy(64GB usb stick) so can't be dd'ed  staight across. I'm going to have to modify the larger partition first so am closing this thanks for the help and info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 32 GB target drive

If you want to clone to a 32 GB target drive, there is a risk, that it is slightly smaller than the original drive, so that the last partition will be truncated.

In that is the case you must edit the partition table of the original drive (or a cloned copy, which is not truncated) to make the last partition fit within the available drive space of the target drive. Boot from another drive and use **gparted** for this purpose.

After that you can clone with mkusb as described below.

### 64 GB target drive

When the last partition ends at sector 61069311, there will be plenty of drive space in the target with nominally 64 GB (120127487 sectors). You should be able to use mkusb to clone it. Use **mkusb version 12** alias **`dus`**. You can use the command line

```
dus /dev/sdx
```

where **`x`** is the drive letter of the source (the original drive or a cloned copy, that is not truncated).

**mkusb** has built-in routines to create a backup partition table at the tail end of the target device for the GUID partition table (GPT).

See the following links,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```

[Expansion and imaging from a compressed image file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Expansion_and_imaging_from_a_compressed_image_file)

### Final tweaks

After cloning to a 64 GB drive, approximately half of the target drive is not used, and you can edit the partition table to use the whole drive. The following link might help you do it,

[GrowIt.pdf](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=GrowIt.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to have to modify the larger partition first so am closing this thanks for the help and info
accepted

I should have stated that the original machine had Windows 10 installed which occupied about 24GB of the 32GB available! so there wasn't enough room to install linux alongside. The only time I will want to restore this abomination is when I'm ready to dispose of the machine.

Comment: Good luck with mkusb! -- Please tell us the result; if it does not work, we have to try some other method, if it works, fine.